# Remove email addresses from Python list using .rstrip("@")

Tags: python, list, character, strip

I have a list of email addresses and I would like to remove everything after "@". My code looks like this so far:

`user_emails = ['me@organization.org', 'you@organization.org', name@organization.org']
emails = [user.rstrip("@") for user in user_emails]`

But nothing changes when I run this code. When I run:

`emails = [user.strip("@organization.org") for user in user_emails]`

The @ is removed but so is the character to the left of it, which is no good for me.

Is there something I should be doing to remove this character?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: `strip`, `rstrip`, and `lstrip` are for removing characters at both ends, the beginning, or the end of strings respectively, not the middle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rstrip("@")` doesn't work because there is no `@` on the right of the string.

`rstrip("@organization.org")` removes more than `@organization.org` when there is an O, R, G, A, N, I, Z, T, O, or N at the end of the username portion of the email address. Remember that `rstrip()` (and its cousins) remove *any* of the listed characters, not the string you provide.

A common solution is to split on the `@` symbol and take the first item of the returned list.

```
addresses = [addr.split("@", 1)[0] for addr in user_addresses]
```

(Naming is important. I used `user_addresses` instead of `user_email` because you don't have the users' e-mails, you have their e-mail *addresses.)*

The common solution does create a (small) temporary list for each address processed. This memory is reused almost immediately by the next iteration, so it is unlikely to have any serious detrimental effects. Still, if you want to avoid creating lists you don't need, you can use `str.find()` to find the `@` and slice off the domain part.

```
addresses = [addr[:addr.find("@")] for addr in user_addresses]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to split on `'@'` and take first part:

```
user_emails = ['me@organization.org', 'you@organization.org', 'name@organization.org']
emails = [user.split("@")[0] for user in user_emails]
```

If you really wanted to use `.rstrip()`, you can do:

```
emails = [user.rstrip("@organization.org") for user in user_emails]
```

Be careful with using `.rstrip()` here. Something like `'foo@organization.org'.rstrip("@organization.org")` yields a different answer.

`.rstrip()` removes characters from right end.

For example:

```
>>> 'asd@'.rstrip('@') 
asd
>>> 'asd@a'.rstrip('@')
asd@a
```

Comment: Why would I need `.rstrip()` if I'm typing everything to the right of the "@" anyways?

Comment: @userfriendly, I was demonstrating the use of `.rstrip()`. You don't need it here in this example.

Comment: `rstrip()` is the wrong tool for this job. Try it with `foo@organization.org` for example.

Comment: @kindall, Yes I do know. It works on OP's inputs, but I guess I should point that out in my answer too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`rstrip` only strips off trailing characters, see [reference here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rstrip.html). The argument is the characters to be stripped.

When you do `user.rstrip("@")`, nothing would happen because `@` is not at the end of `user`, i.e., it's not trailing

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. But why would it remove the character to the left of the "@" if I typed in the whole phrase I wanted to remove? For instance: `.rstrip("@organization.org")` would return a list like `'m', 'yo', 'nam'` (as opposed to `'me', 'you', 'name'`).

Comment: I ran `'me@organization.org'.rstrip('@organization.org')` and got
`'me'`